# CRM 2011 Reporting not showing on IFD

Tags: reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

I have an org that I think worked with reports via IFD at one point.  Today I got notified that they are coming up blank. 
If I run them via localhost\orgname they come up just fine. 
Putting them in via the IFD  URL does they come up empty.

SSRS is installed,

Any suggestions, the internet is not giving me much success.

Comment: Sorry for question with obvious answer - but have you tried to restart CRM and SQL/SSRS servers? Sometimes that helps.

Comment: Yeah Tried it, no better luck on it.